# Double Countdown timer

Tags: javascript, css

I have putting together a javascript for a days countdown, now I have requirement of having two countdown with different dates, is it possible to merge within one script? see original code below

Thanks in advance

```
today = new Date();
BigDayText = "6 August, 2016"
BigDay = new Date(BigDayText);
msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ;
timeLeft = (BigDay.getTime() - today.getTime());
e_daysLeft = timeLeft / msPerDay;
daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);
document.getElementById("daysToGo").innerHTML = daysLeft +  "";
```

Comment: The way you are creating *BigDay* is problematic, far better to use `new Date('2016,7,6)` or parse the text independently of the Date constructor. And yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: not sure how to do it at all, any assistance?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid code duplication, I would recommend you to create a function to calculate the days left for a certain date, so you can passs as many days as a parameter for different events:

```
function daysLeft(BigDay) {
    msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    timeLeft = (BigDay.getTime() - today.getTime());
    e_daysLeft = timeLeft / msPerDay;
    daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);

    return daysLeft;
}
```

Then, call the function with your different dates for future events:

```
daysLeft(new Date("6 August, 2016"))
```

Comment: thanks, I have very little knowledge in javascript, just how do I call this function in my html/CSS? many thanks